Shopify Customer Account API: "client_id invalid" Error on Authorization Request
I'm trying to implement the Shopify Customer Account API following the Shopify documentation here. I'm currently working on the authorization step, where I need to redirect a customer to the login page. However, I'm encountering a 400 (Bad Request) error with the message: client_id invalid.
My setup:
import express from "express";
import dotenv from "dotenv";
import { generateState } from "./utils/index.js";

dotenv.config();
const app = express();

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000;

const clientId = process.env.CLIENT_ID;
const scope = process.env.SCOPE;
const redirectUri = process.env.REDIRECT_URI;
const shopId = process.env.SHOP_ID;
const state = await generateState();

app.get("/auth", (req, res) => {
  const authorizationRequestUrl = new URL(
    `https://shopify.com/${shopId}/auth/oauth/authorize`
  );
  authorizationRequestUrl.searchParams.append("scope", scope);
  authorizationRequestUrl.searchParams.append("client_id", clientId);
  authorizationRequestUrl.searchParams.append("response_type", "code");
  authorizationRequestUrl.searchParams.append("redirect_uri", redirectUri);
  authorizationRequestUrl.searchParams.append("state", state);
  //   authorizationRequestUrl.searchParams.append("nonce", "<nonce>");

  res.redirect(authorizationRequestUrl);
});

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.send("server running on port 5000");
});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server started on port ${port}`);
});





// code for generateState function 
export async function generateState() {
  const timestamp = Date.now().toString();
  const randomString = Math.random().toString(36).substring(2);
  return timestamp + randomString;
}

Error
When I navigate to /auth, I get the following error:
400 (Bad Request) with error: "client_id invalid"
What i have tried
Verified that process.env.CLIENT_ID contains the correct client ID.
Checked that the URL being constructed looks correct.
Ensured that my environment variables are properly loaded.
Here's how my .env file is structured:
CLIENT_ID=<client_id>
SCOPE=<scope>
REDIRECT_URI=<redirect_uri>
SHOP_ID=<shop_id>
PORT=5000



If you verified the full URL is indeed correct, and the client_id is really is what it's supposed to, then one of these must be true: 1. You are wrong, something on your end wasn't correct. 2. Shopify has a bug and you need to contact support.
